# Spy using chai on exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have this situation:

user.js:

```
var a = function() {
    function b() {
        return 5
    }
}

module.exports = a
```

How can I spy the function `b()`?

In my test.js file I have something like this:

```
let us = require('../user)

chai.spy.on(us, 'b', returns => 3);
```

But this doesn't work. How can I solve this using `chai`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible: only exposed functions/methods may be spied on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mock/stub/mock on function `b`, because it is declared as a private function inside function `a`. The mock/stub/spy method needs wrap the original function and add the spy/stub/mock behavior on it.

Since function `b` is private, you can't import it into test file and mock/stub/spy it. That's why it is impossible.